# recursive query postgres12 gives [42P19] ERROR

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am learning recursion in postgres postgres 12 using some parent/child toy Simpsons data.

Here's the create statement:

```
create table Parent(
    parent varchar,
    child varchar
);

insert into Parent (parent, child) values
                                          ('homer', 'bart'),
                                          ('homer', 'lisa'),
                                          ('marge', 'bart'),
                                          ('marge', 'lisa'),
                                          ('abe', 'homer'),
                                          ('ape', 'abe');
```

Now I want to create a table where I have a column for the ancestors and a column for the descendants, which should look like the below:

```
ancestor | descendant
----------------------
homer    | bart
homer    | lisa
marge    | bart
marge    | lisa
abe      | homer
ape      | abe
ape      | homer
abe      | bart
abe      | lisa
ape      | bart
ape      | lisa
```

And my solution yields this error:

`[42P19] ERROR: recursive reference to query "ancestor" must not appear more than once`

Here's my code:

```
with recursive
Ancestor(ancestor, descendant) as
    ((select parent, child from Parent)
     union
     (select a1.ancestor, a2.descendant
      from Ancestor a1, Ancestor a2
      where a1.descendant = a2.ancestor))
select *
from Ancestor;
```

I understand the error, but i don't understand how I can achieve what I want without creating an intermediate table with the cross product of Ancestor with itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally in a recursive CTE, you join to the *original* table not a self join to the recursive table.

If you do this, you get what you want:

```
with recursive Ancestor(ancestor, descendant) as (
      select parent, child
      from Parent
      union all
      select a.ancestor, p.child
      from Ancestor a join
           parent p
           on a.descendant = p.parent
     )
select *
from Ancestor;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=52b7c620cf88bdd9d14654151f3d6416) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the parent table to the CTE:

```
with recursive Ancestor as (
  select parent, child 
  from Parent
  where parent = 'abe'

  union

  select p.parent, p.child
  from parent p
     join ancestor a on a.child = p.parent
)
select *
from Ancestor;
```